# Steam game not launching on primary display

Tags: display, xrandr, steam, window-switching

This is going to drive me crazy. I am having immense issues getting New Worlds to a. Open on the Correct monitor, and b. Run at the correct resolution.

I have 3 monitors, setup using xrandr (Arch, i3). Two 1080p monitors and a 4k monitor designated as primary.

When I launch New World, 75% of the time it launches on the primary display. That random 25% of the time though, it insists on launching on the 1080p display. When it does this, I try to go into video settings in-game to select my 4K monitor for display, but it doesn't show up and the max resolution available is 1080p.

Has anyone else run into similar issues? The only way I've found to resolve it involves removing all data for the game within /{steam_install_location}/steamapps/compatdata/1063730/

Arch w/ Linux Kernel 6.1.1, running New Worlds via Steam/Proton.

Comment: I haven't tried this so have no idea if it would work or not, but maybe [gamescope](https://github.com/Plagman/gamescope) would help with this.  The basic idea is that the game will only see the virtual display created by gamescope, which gamescope can create on your primary monitor (either full screen or a window).  If this works, please write up how you did it and post as an answer below - you can accept your own answer to mark this Q as closed.

Comment: BTW, gamescope is [packaged for Arch](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/gamescope/).   as is [gamescope-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gamescope-git), which I'd guess is a package of the latest bleeding-edge not-tagged-for-release code in gamescope's git repo.